# Changing IP to set location

Tags: internet

I want to change my IP so that if anyone tries to track my location they can't find me.
Is there a way to do this? 
I know it is possible by changing IP address, but I don't have any idea how to do this.
I am trying to download some torrents which are not available in my country.

Answer (score 2):

Your IP address is generally defined by the network you are on.

The way the network is controlled will depend whether you can realistically change the address yourself.

Generally, the router or some other network controller that you connect to defines your IP address and messing with it on a shared network is likely to cause issues for other people and/or servers.

On a personal network however, this is less of an issue.

The other way to hide your IP address is to use a virtual network, either a Virtual Private Network (VPN) or TOR. The latter in particular will hide your IP address from anyone you connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Tor to change your IP. Vuze has option to download torrent files using The Onion Router (Tor).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what software you are using to download torrents. Some of them allow you to specify a proxy server ( http://torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=12 ). If your torrent client can't use a proxy, try proxifier : https://www.proxifier.com/
It will try to make all your traffic pass through a proxy.
You can also use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a proxy or a VPN. Pretty much every torrent client supports proxies but VPN is easier to set-up. In my experience [Hotspot Shield](http://www.hotspotshield.com/) is the best free VPN service. This should allow you to bypass geo-restrictions.

But keep in mind that most of these services keep a log of you activities and you are not truly anonymous. If you want true anonymity use [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) or a VPN that doesn't keep logs.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, the answer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you are interested in hiding your own ip and pretending to be someone else there are some softwares available ( some are free to try and some are paid).One example is Hidemyass which is also available as addon for google chrome I guess.And if you are using Firefox browser there is this One-click Proxy and other large number of addons.(choose which one works for you).For downloading torrent files I guess the above things will be more than enough becos once connected with your torrent software it will possibly connect to peers and seeds all over the world!Hope this answer is useful to You!!